# Transfer money from US to India

Tags: india, money-transfer, international-transfer, inr-indian-rupee

I have money in my USA account,I wish to transfer that to my Indian Account. What is the best way to send a large amount of money say $50,000 to $100,000 to India from USA?  Thank you!